# How to fix RestTemplate NullPointerException in spring boot?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

```
@Service
public class RequestSender {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestSender.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public MbsFtResponseData sendJsonDataToMBS(final MBSTransactionData transactionData) {
        String mbsUrl = MBSConfigConstants.mbsUrl;
        try {
            logger.info("Sending request method Is Initiated");
            HttpEntity<MBSTransactionData> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(transactionData);
            ResponseEntity<MbsFtResponseData> response = restTemplate.exchange(mbsUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,
                    MbsFtResponseData.class);
            if (response != null) {
                HttpStatus status = response.getStatusCode();
                if (status.is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    logger.info("Response getting back is succeded with the status code {}", status.value());
                    return response.getBody();
                } else {
                    logger.error("ERROR Response getting back is  with the status code {}", status.value());
                    throw new BBPSMBSException("Error is while connecting to mBS server", status.value());
                }
            } else {
                logger.error("Null value::::::::::::response is null");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("ERROR :::{}:: is occered ", e.getCause());
        }
        return new MbsFtResponseData("Server Not responding or Busy", 500, "FAILED");
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.npst.bbps.middleware.mbs.RequestSender.sendJsonDataToMBS(RequestSender.java:26)  at com.npst.bbps.middleware.mbs.MbsftServiceImpl.mbsFundTransfer(MbsftServiceImpl.java:27)  at com.npst.bbps.middleware.controller.ThirdPartyIntegrationCtrl.initiateRefund(ThirdPartyIntegrationCtrl.java:64)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line number 26 in your code? At that line, your application receives a NULL value that it can't handle.

Comment: Please do provide complete info in query. Cannot make out what is null in the original post.

Comment: Check the null reference on line 26

Comment: Can you please show your bean configuration for `restTemplate` ?

Comment: its workong now 
@Autowiring is not working myside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RestTemplate` bean is not found in the `BeanFactory`, because you wouldn't configured.

You have to define a bean like below in the configuration file.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

   @Bean
   public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
      return new RestTemplate();
   }

}
```

Comment: i have already done with
but @Autowiring is not working that time 
now its working fine